# How to detect ASAN (Address Sanitizer) errors of subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess, address-sanitizer

In python, my application needs to create subprocesses using modules like [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Usually, these subprocesses are C/C++ programs hardened with ASAN ([Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)).

I'd like to be able to detect if a subprocess is crashed by asan errors and still be able to collect the asan report.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If child processes abort due to errors discovered by Asan, they will print detailed error message to stderr. Your root application can then detect that subprocess terminated with non-zero exit code and print it's stderr for inspection.

Alternatively, you can ask Asan to store error reports in file system via

```
# Error reports will be saved to path/to/asan/logs/asan.PID files
$ export ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path=path/to/asan/logs/asan
$ ./main.py
```

Comment: Do you mean that export `ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path=path/to/asan/logs/asan` ?  @yugr

Answer (score 0):

The subprocess module has facilities for capturing stdout and stderr. The documentation is quite helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

You can do it like this for example:

```
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    subprocess.run(["my_program", "--flag", "my_param", input, output],
                   check=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    # You can now query stderr with err.stderr and do what you want with it:
    # printing, saving etc. for example:
    if "address_sanitizer" in err.stderr:
         print(err.stderr, file=sys.stderr)
    raise err  # Raise the error to make you program crash if desired
```

Alternatively you can run the program without `check=True`.

```
import subprocess
import sys

program_result= subprocess.run(["my_program", "--flag", "my_param", input, output],
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if program_result.return_code != 0:
     print(program_result.stderr, file=sys.stderr)
     program_result.check_output()  # This will raise an error
```